# Losing few bytes on TCP writing/reading of a string as a byte array

Tags: c#, .net-core, networking, tcp

I'm trying to create a simple upload/recieve file functionality using TCP. What im doing is attempting a handshake first by sending a string "READY" to the recieving end and then the recieving end should reply back with "READY". The problem im facing is that every time i send those packets I lose the first 4 characters and I get a "Y".

Since im sending only 5 characters im pretty sure the buffer is enough, also I've tried with larger strings and the output is the same: every character EXCEPT for the first 4. My question is what am I missing? How could those 4 bytes be lost every single time? Is it possible for the stream to send bytes without anything ready to listen to the stream?

Here is what i have in the client:

```cs
public static async Task<bool> UploadFile(AppClient client, string path)
{
        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.TcpClient.GetStream();
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                // Send the "READY" packet to the receiver.
                var packet = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("READY");
                await stream.WriteAsync(packet, 0, packet.Length);

                // Wait for the "READY" packet from the receiver.
                packet = new byte[1024];
                await stream.ReadAsync(packet, 0, packet.Length);
                var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(packet).TrimEnd('\0');
                Debug.WriteLine(response);

                // If the receiver is ready, send the file.
                if (response == "READY")
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("HERE I SHOULD IMPLEMENT THE ACTUAL SENDING");
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("NOT READY");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false; // TODO: ACTUAL ERROR HANDLING
        }
}
```

Here is what I have on the server:

```cs
public async Task<bool> ReceiveFile(string filePath)
{
        try
        {
            var stream = _appClient.TcpClient.GetStream();
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(filePath))
            {
                // Wait for the "READY" packet from the sender.
                var packet = new byte[1024];
                await stream.ReadAsync(packet, 0, packet.Length);
                var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(packet).TrimEnd('\0');

                // If the sender is ready, send the "READY" packet back.
                if (response == "READY")
                {
                    packet = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("READY");
                    await stream.WriteAsync(packet, 0, packet.Length);

                    // Implement receiveing the file from the sender
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false; // TODO: ACTUAL ERROR HANDLING
        }
}
```

I'll really appreciate if someone manages to give me an explanation to why this would happen.

Comment: Not sure why you are losing the beginning of the packet, but you are making a fundamental mistake anyway: TCP streams do not guarantee that a single `Write` results in a single `Read` at the other end. The data you send may be split into multiple sections, or combined with other sections. You need to use some kind of message framing. See also https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html

Comment: Also: you should use the return value of `ReadAsync` and then use this GetString [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=net-8.0#system-text-encoding-getstring(system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32)) to convert only those bytes that were actually received.

Comment: Unless you have some specific reason to use raw TCP, I would suggest using a higher level protocol/library. These take care of things like message framing, and combined with a serializer, makes it very easy to transfer entire objects. There are plenty to chose, MQTT, gRPC, http, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of framing as Charlieface already mentioned. Easiest would be an e.g. 4 bytes length header
or encapsulate in e.g. STX (0x2), ETX (0x3) (ensure that these boundaries do not occur in your file --> agree to use "text" files
only or convert to base64 prior to send it).

A single read is likely to fail as the transport can have delays. Read in a loop until all your expected data is present
or some error condition occur.
Using TrimEnd('\0') might remove expected data as well

Use a higher protocol if possible. It can save you from most of the headache.
Http for instance uses a length header (Content-Length)